in pyqt5 I want to create Splash Screen in my WhatsApp Ui project but there is two window created how to solve it
I want to create a splash screen on my fluent Ui, but in this Ui window the title bar's button is there. I don't want this. I am beginner so help me please . I try to fix this code but I failed so tell me how  can I fix it. when I run this code window open successfully but the icon is visible. There is no any error so tell me how can I fix it
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication,QStackedWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QSize,QEventLoop,QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from temp import First_page,Second_page,Third_page
from qfluentwidgets import SplashScreen
from qframelesswindow import FramelessWindow 

class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initwindow()
        self.initUi()
        self.window()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(700, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('WhatsApp')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\\Users\\NSG\\Desktop\\qfluent widget\\whatsapp3-removebg-preview.png'))

        self.splashScreen = SplashScreen(self.windowIcon(), self)
        self.splashScreen.setIconSize(QSize(333, 333))

        self.show()

        # create other subinterfaces
        self.createSubInterface()

        # close splash screen
        self.splashScreen.finish()
     
    def createSubInterface(self):
        loop = QEventLoop(self)
        QTimer.singleShot(4000,loop.quit)
        loop.exec()

    def initwindow(self):
            self.resize(900,400)
            self.setWindowTitle('WhatsApp')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\\Users\\NSG\\Desktop\\qfluent widget\\whatsapp_logo.png'))
            
            desktop = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
            w,h = desktop.width(),desktop.height()
            self.move(w//2 - self.width(), h//2 - self.height())

    def window(self):

        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.first_page = First_page(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.first_page)

        self.second_page = Second_page(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.second_page)

        self.third_page = Third_page(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.third_page)

    def show_first_page(self):
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.first_page)

    def show_second_page(self):
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.second_page)

    def show_third_page(self):
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.third_page)

if __name__=='__main__':
    QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Mainwindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())





from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,QStyle,QVBoxLayout,QToolButton,QLabel, QFrame,QSizePolicy,QSpacerItem,QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap
from qfluentwidgets import BodyLabel,PrimaryPushButton,PushButton,DropDownPushButton,FluentIcon,Action,RoundMenu

class First_page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("whatsapp3_logo-removebg-preview.png")
        self.init_ui(parent)

    def init_ui(self,parant):

        layout1 = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout1.addStretch(1)

        self.image_label = QLabel(self)
        self.update_image_size(200,200)    
        layout1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout1.addWidget(self.image_label)

        layout1.addStretch(0)

        label1 = QLabel("Welcome to WhatsApp")
        label1.setFont(QFont("Arial",15, QFont.Bold))
        label1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout1.addWidget(label1)

        layout1.addSpacing(17)

        label2 = QLabel("A simpal,reliable and private way to use WhatsApp on your computer")
        label2.setFont(QFont("Arial",10))
        label2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout1.addWidget(label2)

        layout1.addSpacing(20)

        button = PrimaryPushButton("Get started")
        button.setFixedSize(180,30)
        button.clicked.connect(parant.show_second_page)
        layout1.addWidget(button,alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout1.addSpacing(20)

        label3 = QLabel("Version 2.2440.9.0")
        label3.setFont(QFont("Arial",10))
        label3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout1.addWidget(label3)

        layout1.addStretch(1)

    def update_image_size(self,width,height):
        scaled_Pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(width,height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(scaled_Pixmap)
    
    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        new_width = self.width() * 0.5
        new_height = self.height() * 0.5
        self.update_image_size(int(new_width),int(new_height))
        super().resizeEvent(event)

class Second_page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui(parent)

    def init_ui(self, parent):  
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(32, 32, 32, 32)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
     
        central_frame = QFrame(self)
        central_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-radius: 10px")
        central_frame.setMinimumSize(900, 600)
        central_frame.setMaximumWidth(500)
        
        central_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_frame)

        instruction = BodyLabel(
            "<b style='font-size:18px;'>To set up WhatsApp on your computer</b><br><br>"
            "<span style='color: gray;'>1. Open WhatsApp on your phone</span><br><br>"
            "<span style='color: gray;'>2. Tap <b>Menu</b> on Android, or <b>Settings</b> on iPhone</span><br><br>"
            "<span style='color: gray;'>3. Tap <b>Linked devices</b> and then <b>Link a device</b></span><br><br>"
            "<span style='color: gray;'>4. Point your phone at this screen to capture the QR code</span><br><br>"
        )
        
        instruction.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        instruction.setFont(QFont("Arial", 11))
        instruction.setStyleSheet("padding-left: 100px; line-height: 100px;padding-top:100px;")
        instruction.setWordWrap(True)

        qr_label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("qr2.png")  
        qr_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        qr_label.setStyleSheet("padding-top:100px; padding-right:100px;")
        qr_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        line_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        line_layout.addWidget(instruction)
        line_layout.addWidget(qr_label)

        central_layout.addLayout(line_layout)

        link_label = BodyLabel("<a href='#' style='color: green;'>Link with phone number</a>")
        link_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        link_label.linkActivated.connect(parent.show_third_page)
        link_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 9, QFont.Bold))
        link_label.setStyleSheet("padding-left: 100px;padding-bottom: 100px")  

        central_layout.addWidget(link_label)

        layout.addWidget(central_frame)

        back_button = QToolButton(self)
        back_button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ArrowBack))
        back_button.clicked.connect(parent.show_first_page)

        layout.addWidget(back_button, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

        self.setLayout(layout)



class Third_page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parant):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui(parant)

    def init_ui(self,parant):

        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.setContentsMargins(1,10,10,10)
        layout2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        central_frame = QFrame(self)
        central_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        central_frame.setFixedSize(888,500)
        # central_frame.setM(500)

        central_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_frame)
        
        label = BodyLabel("<b>Enter phone number</b>")
        label.setFont(QFont("Arial",14))
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        central_layout.addWidget(label)

        label2 = BodyLabel("Select a country and add your phone number")
        label2.setStyleSheet("padding-bottom: 100px;")
        label2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        central_layout.addWidget(label2)
        central_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,290)

        button2 = DropDownPushButton(FluentIcon.MAIL, 'Email')
        # Create menu
        menu = RoundMenu(parent=button2)
        menu.addAction(Action(FluentIcon.BASKETBALL, 'Basketball', triggered=lambda: print("What are you doing?")))
        menu.addAction(Action(FluentIcon.ALBUM, 'Sing', triggered=lambda: print("I like singing, rapping, and dancing")))
        menu.addAction(Action(FluentIcon.MUSIC, 'Music', triggered=lambda: print("Just because you are so beautiful")))
        # Add menu
        button2.setMenu(menu)

        central_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        central_layout.addWidget(button2)


        layout2.addWidget(central_frame, alignment= Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setLayout(layout2)
    
        



Making the following changes will display a 3 second splash screen which will display the image only. It does not block the main program from starting until the splash screen closes. Also, it centers the splash screen and the main program screen.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QStackedWidget, QDesktopWidget, QSplashScreen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from a_pyqt5_ui import First_page, Second_page, Third_page


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        splash_screen_width = 700
        splash_screen_height = 600
        self.setFixedSize(960, 720)  # main window dimensions
        self.setWindowTitle('WhatsApp')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('<your splash image>'))

        pixmap = QPixmap('<your splash image>').scaled(
            splash_screen_width, splash_screen_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio
        )
        self.splashScreen = QSplashScreen(pixmap, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        screen_geometry = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        x = (screen_geometry.width() - splash_screen_width) // 2
        y = (screen_geometry.height() - splash_screen_height) // 2
        self.splashScreen.move(x, y)

        self.splashScreen.show()
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.show_main_window)

        self.center_main_window()
        self.window()

    def show_main_window(self):
        self.splashScreen.finish(self)
        self.show()

    def center_main_window(self):
        screen_geometry = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        frame_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        frame_geometry.moveCenter(screen_geometry.center())
        self.move(frame_geometry.topLeft())


The OP claims that their problem is not about displaying the splash screen, but that it shows a title bar they don't want: "the title bar's button is there. I don't want this".

@musicamante, I have edited my answer to remove the icon and title bar from the splash screen window.

At that point, it makes little sense to use that "SplashScreen" class, as the basic (and more consistent) QSplashScreen would suffice. Don't use time.sleep(), it's always inappropriate in GUI; your previous usage of QTimer.singleShot() was more correct.

I have edited my answer to incorporate the changes suggested by @musicamante.

That's better, thanks. Note that QDesktopWidget has been deprecated for years, use QScreen related functions (eg: QApplication.primaryScreen()).
